# Firebase stub transaction

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, sinon, stubbing

I am trying to stub a transaction over real time database table.The transaction is inside a function called by a trigger (non HTTP). I can fire the trigger, but I'm not able to stub transaction like this:

```
var codeRef = admin.database().ref('last_code')
return codeRef.transaction(function (currentCode) {
    return currentCode + 1
})
    .then(result => {
        const {error, committed, snapshot} = result
        return snapshot.val()
    })
```

I am using stub Sinon with mocha [Unit testing of Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing). This is the way I tried:

```
const test = require('firebase-functions-test')();
adminInitStub = sinon.stub(admin, 'initializeApp');
// Now we can require index.js and save the exports inside a namespace called myFunctions.
myFunctions = require('../index');
const refParam = 'last_code';
const databaseStub = sinon.stub();
const refStub = sinon.stub();
const transactionStub = sinon.stub();
Object.defineProperty(admin, 'database', { get: () => databaseStub });
databaseStub.returns({ ref: refStub });
refStub.withArgs(refParam).returns({transaction: function(code) => ({committed: true, snapshot: 999});
```

But stub transaction fails. I am sure that last line is incorrect, but don't see the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolve in this way:

```
 const obj = {
        a: (() => function(code){
          return 999
        })};

  let dbSnap = {
          val: function() {
              return 999;
          }
       };
var resolveStub = sinon.stub(obj,"a");
const result = {"error": null, "committed" : true, "snapshot" : dbSnap};
resolveStub.resolves(result);
refStub.withArgs("last_booking_code").returns({transaction:  resolveStub});
```